# "comes by" or "comes past"?

Tags: word-choice

Restlessly roaming the corridors of the hospital while her mom is in surgery, Joan comes by/past the room where the old man she talked to last month had been. The room was now empty.

(Joan doesn't intend to go there. She just comes by/past it by accident and remembers that it was that room. She doesn't necessarily enters the room, just comes by/past it in the corridor.)

Should it be "comes by" or "comes past"?

Comment: Joan goes by the room etc.

Comment: I think you may be looking for "comes upon"

Answer (score 0):

The normal use would be *comes past*. If you said *comes by* people would probably understand you but it would sound odd.

Note also that there is a separate use of *comes by* to mean *come into possession of* although this is a bit archaic.

As KateBunting pointed out in a comment it might be better to say *goes past* unless the person is known to be moving towards the narrator.

In general verbs of motion can either take *past* or *by* here and although *past* always seems to work using *by* is quite natural with some.

*Walks, runs, drives* all sound natural with *by* as well as *past*

*Climbs, crawls* sound slightly odd to me with *by*

The only exception to the rule of using *past* that occurs to me is the verb *pass* itself. Here you would either *pass the door* or *pass by the door* but not *pass past the door*

Comment: _Goes past_ or _passes_ would be better. _Comes past_ is only appropriate if Joan is approaching the person telling the story.

Comment: @KateBunting I agree, it is a bit ambiguous as to what exactly is going on in the story.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20by), **come by** in US English means "to make a visit", which is deninitely not appropriate in this context. In the UK, it only has the **acquire** meaning that @mdewey mentions.

Futhermore, we only use the word **come** if the person is moving toward the speaker, for example:

> He came to my office yesterday

It would be better to use the verb **[pass](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pass)**, which means "to move in a path so as to approach and continue beyond something : move past", or at least say "walk past".